# django-cors-headers not work in for patch method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # default django apps
    'jazzmin',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Optional: Django admin theme (must be before django.contrib.admin)



    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    'corsheaders',

    'treebeard',
    'UserAccount.apps.UseraccountConfig',
    'CompanyInfo.apps.CompanyInfoConfig',
    'Backup.apps.BackupConfig',
    'FinancialPeriod',
    'Inventory.apps.InventoryConfig',
    'Product.apps.ProductConfig',

]
```

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False
default_headers = (
    "accept",
    "accept-encoding",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "dnt",
    "origin",
    "user-agent",
    "x-csrftoken",
    "x-requested-with",
)

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
]
```

django == 3.1
django-cors-headers == 3.5.0

Everything is normal, but just patch method is not work !!
all methods work just and just patch method return
Access to XMLHttpRequest at ... from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Were you able to find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser you're testing with, the issue might be due to one or more extensions installed. One such example is the [Allow CORS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) extension.

To know for certain if this is the issue, you can either:

- Test using a different browser or
- Test using the same browser in a private browsing window. Unless configured
  otherwise, most extensions are usually disabled in private browsing
  sessions, so any installed extensions will be disabled.